# MySQL unknown table engine innodb

Tags: mysql, drupal, innodb

I am trying to migrate a test website on drupal onto a live server on Amazon ec2. I migrated the database using phpmyadmin, and tried to access the site. I got this error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1286 Unknown table engine 'InnoDB': SELECT expire, value FROM {semaphore} WHERE name = :name; Array ( [:name] => variable_init ) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /var/www/includes/lock.inc).

I believe the problem here is that MySQL doesn't have InnoDB. I have looked through the my.cnf file and there is no line that says `skip-innodb`.

I have tried `show engines` and it showed a bunch of engines but not innodb.
I have tried restarting my server and deleting the logfile, just like has been suggested previously, but that didn't work.

Maybe what needs to be done is to somehow install the Innodb engine. Could you tell me how I may do that?

Comment: Doy have any innodb config lines eg. # Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
innodb_data_home_dir =

Comment: I have no innodb config lines in my my.cnf file. There is only this `
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!`
By the way this my.cnf file lives in /etc/mysql, I am kind of confused because in my /var/lib/mysql directory there is no my.cnf file

Comment: Do you have a ibdata1 in that location? And could you post a nice formatted version of SHOW ENGINES;

Comment: I'm not sure how I should format it, but it includes MyISAM, MRG_MYISAM, BLACKHOLE, CSV, MEMORY, FEDERATED (support=no), and ARCHIVE.

Comment: in /var/lib/mysql and /etc/mysql there is a file ibdata1, however in /var/lib/mysql there is also a file ib_logfile0, but in /etc/mysql there is no such file, because earlier I deleted it.

Comment: I'm going to try installing an innodb plugin; just came across it on mysql's website. Thanks and I'll update if it works

Comment: It sounds like it is installed how about creating a test table just to see. CREATE TABLE foo (bar int) ENGINE=INNODB;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Debian 6 this can also happen when you change the innodb_log_file_size parameter... some times mysql does not start.. but other times it just starts up bud disables innodb engine... so solution is to remove ib_logfiles from /var/lib/mysql and restart mysql

Answer (score 0):

Look in your mysql error log.  Run

```
select @@log_error;
```

To see where exactly that is.

There is probably something in there telling why it failed on startup.  (Perhaps trying to allocate more buffer pool than you have memory?)

Comment: I'm sorry where would the error log be located? 
I have a mysql directory in /etc/mysql, a mysql directory /etc/mysql/mysql, and a directory /var/lib/mysql

Another thing is that when I open ib_logfile0 inside var/lib/mysql it yields some funny characters

Comment: I was trying to communicate where to find the error log by running the select @@log_error; query.  That will tell you exactly where it is.  It might be /var/log/mysql/mysql.err.  Has Innodb always worked on this server?  Did you try to just copy the ibdata file over from another server?

Comment: thanks for the help; I actually just terminated the ec2 instance and made a new one; I'll let you know if the problem persists

Comment: I made a new ec2 instance and everything was fine. I did install drupal first, however, so that my have been my problem. It is still quite mysterious to me however. Thank you